# Robbins-Monro condition and Exponential Moving Average

Tags: estimation

I have been working with incremental parameter update, mainly incremental sample mean update. That is, for $k$-th iteration, the parameter $\theta^{(k)}$ is updated as

$$
\theta^{(k)} = \theta^{(k-1)} + \alpha^{(k)} (\hat{\theta}^{(k)} - \theta^{(k-1)})  
$$

where $\hat{\theta}^{(k)}$ is the estimation target (or $k$-th observation of estimation) and $\alpha^{(k)}$ is the stepsize for $k$-th update.

In most literature, $\alpha^{(k)}$ is chosen to satisfy the Robbins-Monro conditions which is

$$
\lim_{k \to \infty} \alpha(k) = 0 \\
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \alpha(k) = \infty \\
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \alpha^{2}(k) = 0 
$$

since these conditions ensure the convergence. Typically it is implemented as $\alpha(k)=k^{-p}$ where $p \in (0.5, 1]$.

However, in other literatures, I have seen using constant stepsize, which is often refered as an exponentially weighted mean or exponential moving average. Although it clearly violates Robbins-Monro conditions, it seems to work fine with most of them especially with non-stationary system cases

It is intuitively understandable since constant stepsize allows forgetting old values, however, I am curious if there is some mathematical derivation or theoretical studies of the validness of exponential moving average rather than 'it just works.'

Also, can I assume that it is always better to use constant stepsize than decreasing stepsize in, for example, deep learning situation where layrer inputs are non-stationary?

Moreover, if the stepsize selection differs depend on the situation, is there another considerable choice of stepsize that is also widely used?